# User logout when browser closes

Tags: 7, users

Is there a way to automatically log out users when they close a browser? 
I've tried to set (settings.php)

`ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 0);

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);`

but this doesn't work. Seems to me like it has anything to do with the 'sid' stored in the 'sessions' table?

Comment: this [article](http://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/drupal-end-session-on-closing-the-browser/) has info on D6, not sure if it will work in D7

Comment: This doesn't work in D7 because the session id is stored in 'sessions' table

Comment: The solution @mototribe proposed works for me in IE, Firefox, Chrome. Did have to flush the cache to clear old settings. Here's another [more recent article](http://geroldm.com/2011/11/drupal-logout-user-when-browser-is-closed/) recommending the same solution.

Comment: The session id is also stored in the sessions table in D6. There's absolutely no reason why the suggested `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  0);` wouldn't work in D7.

Comment: see my comment below, ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0); should work. Where core sets a session cookie it uses `session_get_cookie_params` to read the parameters which should change by that ini_set.

Comment: This method work correctly if you compeletly close browser, if you just clost the drupal tab in firefox user seesion_cookie still alived but if you close firefox compeletly it works. do you find solution for this?

Comment: There's one reason why this wouldn't work. In a browser with tabs, the session only clears when the whole browser is closed, not the tab alone. Other than that, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [session_expire](http://drupal.org/project/session_expire) module, and this module's page has some information about garbage collector confs and stuff.